# How to list system packages uninstalled (for a user) via ADB?

Tags: adb, system-apps

I want to research the bloatware that I disabled using `pm uninstall -k –user 0 <package>` and I just realized that I don't know how to make a list of those specific apps. I can list the file names stored in `/system/app` but it would be very tedious to find which ones are disabled and also to figure out their package names. `pm list` has a `-d` option to display disabled apps, but it only works for apps disabled from within the android menu.

If it helps, the phone in mind is not rooted and it is running Android 6.0.1.

Answer (score 3):

```
pm list packages -u
```

This lists all such 'uninstalled' packages in the system.

Comment: Note that `pm list packages -u` also includes installed packages (help says "also include uninstalled packages", so you need to diff it against `pm list packages` without the `-u`). Further, somewhere around Android 7, `pm list packages` was replaced by `cmd package list`.

Comment: Like @Izzy said you need to diff both commands: `diff <(adb shell pm list packages) <(adb shell pm list packages -u)`

Comment: Right, thanks for the diff command.

Comment: This should be put on the  answer area.