# Howto get ONLY uninstalled packages list with associated apk (if any)?

Tags: adb, apk, shell, uninstallation, cleanup

(rooted galaxy j5 7.1.1)

As `pm list packages -u` shows ALL packages including uninstalled (at least on my system), what should be the right command to show ONLY uninstalled apps?
Or is this an unexpected behavior that would mean I've something wrong?

Options like -u -f -s are giving inclusive (OR type of) results. Is there a way to get exclusive AND type of result? Like, "uninstalled, system apps with their associated apk, if any). Looks easy, but it just doesn't work for me. Or should it?

Comment: Related: [the comment thread on the answer of 'How to list system packages uninstalled (for a user) via ADB?'](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/226964/how-to-list-system-packages-uninstalled-for-a-user-via-adb/226966#comment296469_226966)

Comment: Not so easy. Related... but doesn't give answer to my question.

Comment: To compare outputs of "cmd package list packages" and "cmd package list packages -u" by "diff" makes a line by line comparison and won't just sort uninstalled apps, only if the files to compare are first edited by hand... which would obviously solve the problem the hard way, what wasn't the goal.

Comment: I haven't researched further about this, but perhaps there's no easy way without additional text processing.

Comment: If you want a solution like [this](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/250521/218526), I have a shell script.