# How to reinstall an uninstalled system bloatware app through ADB?

Tags: bloatware

My phone is an unrooted Oppo A1K running Android 9.0. Yesterday when removing bloatware from my phone, I accidentally uninstalled a system app using the adb command;

when I Open MY PHOTOS and click on send or share option in my photos, app automatically crashes I Don't want to factory reset my device. Please tell me another way...

Comment: On unrooted devices the `adb pm uninstall` command can not really uninstall a system app, only disabling it, so the apps should still be there. You should be able to [list them](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/226964/2241) and then you should able to re-enable them using `adb shell pm enable PACKAGE`

Comment: @Robert, shouldn't this be an answer?

Comment: @RohitGupta As the question does not include the exact commands used to disable the packages I wasn't sure if the `pm enable` commands works in all situations.